# How does ldap work on a client?

Tags: centos, ldap

This is on CentOS

I read the various openldap howto's, they mention /etc/openldap/ldap.conf and editing /etc/nsswitch.conf

for example:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-ldap-pam.html

I had openldap-clients installed. Thats all I know for sure that's what I should do. I don't know what else to do or try. Isn't there supposed to be an ldap binary somewhere that handles server connections or something? An instance of slapd on the client ? I really don't understand how this works on the client-side. The goal right now is to simply have users defined in ldap database to be able to ssh into client machines on my local network.

ldap.conf also has symbolic links in the various places mentioned in different tutorials:

```
/etc/openldap/ldap.conf #real file                                                                                                                                    
/etc/ssh/ldap.conf                                                                                                                                                     
/etc/ldap.conf
```

ldap.conf:

```
pam_login_attribute uid

base dc=lan,dc=archives,dc=net
uri ldap://directory.lan.archives.net/
pam_min_uid 100
#pam_password_prohibit_message Please visit http://accounts.cs.sunyit.edu/ to change your password.
nss_base_passwd         ou=people,dc=lan,dc=archives,dc=net
nss_base_shadow         ou=people,dc=lan,dc=archives,dc=net
nss_base_group          ou=groups,dc=lan,dc=archives,dc=net
bind_policy soft

# Enable SSL
ssl start_tls
tls_reqcert demand
TLS_CACERT /etc/pki/tls/certs/archivesCA.crt

# Extra SSL settings
#tls_checkpeer no
#tls_reqcert never

# Disable SSL
#ssl off
#TLS never

timelimit 10
bind_timelimit 10
idle_timelimit 3600

#sudoers_base ou=sudoers,dc=lan,dc=archives,dc=net

# Require host tag in ldap
# System hostname must match DNS records
#pam_check_host_attr yes
```

nsswitch.conf:

```
...
passwd:     files sss ldap
shadow:     files sss ldap
group:      files sss ldap
...
```

my /etc/sssd/sssd.conf:

```
[domain/LDAP]
id_provider = ldap
cache_credentials = False
ldap_search_base = dc=lan,dc=archives,dc=net
ldap_uri = ldap://directory.lan.archives.net/
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis

id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
#chpass_provider = ldap
ldap_network_timeout = 3

ldap_id_use_start_tls = True
ldap_tls_reqcert = demand

#ldap_tls_cacert = /opt/work/certs/archivesCA.crt
#ldap_tls_reqcert = never

[sssd]
domains = LDAP
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = default

[nss]
filter_users = root,ldap,named,avahi,haldaemon,dbus,radiusd,news,nscd
```

Comment: I find it odd that you have `sss` in `nsswitch.conf`, but mention `/etc/sshd/ldap.conf`. Shouldn't an `sssd` configuration file be involved?

Comment: I'm not sure. I thought sssd was a service tailor made for this type of thing.

Comment: Yes, `sssd`, `nslcd`, etc. are services meant for this type of thing, but `sssd` is not for only LDAP. You still have to configure it to use LDAP. I haven't used `sssd`, but I understand it is fairly general in what it supports. `nslcd`, OTOH is only for LDAP, I think.

Comment: Ok. I got something for sssd.conf. I added it to the question